# Sub Lie algebra noncohomologous to zero

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebra-cohomology

Let $g$ be a Lie algebra and $h$ a subalgebra of $g$. The embedding $h\subset g$ induces a map on the cohomology groups $H^*(g)\to H^*(h)$. I want to determine whether this map is surjective. What are some known results/criteria for this property? (The example of my interest involves infinite dimensional graded Lie algebras.)

Comment: The title is not very helpful: it has too little to do with the question itself, I think.

Comment: On a more serious note: is there a reason you prefer cohomology to homology? It might be more natural to ask (and hope for someone to answer) when an embedding of algebras induces the embedding of homology. Also, can you give some instances of cases of interest, or at least indicate the nature of these cases? I have a range of both examples and non-examples of these for infinite-dimensional Lie algebras, but I wonder if those are related at all to cases you are thinking about.

Comment: The examples I'm thinking about are Lie algebras $g_N$ defined by polynomial rings with coefficients taking value in simple Lie algebra $A_N$, and the map is from $H^*(g_N)$ to $H^*(g_{N-1})$.

Comment: You mean $g_N=\mathfrak{sl}_N\otimes\mathbb{C}[t]$? Or polynomials with more than one variable? In the case of one variable, $H^*(g_N)=H^*(\mathfrak{sl}_N)$, and so it is easy to see that surjectivity indeed holds. Maybe using the adjoint action of $\mathfrak{sl}_{N-1}$ on both sides, it might be reasonably easy to prove it even without knowing the answer.

Comment: More than one variable - in fact, what I want is n commuting variables $t_i$ and m anti-commuting variables $\theta_j$. Could you elaborate on your comments, firstly why tensoring with C[t] does not change the cohomology of $sl(N)$, and secondly how do you use the adjoint action of $sl(N-1)$ to prove the surjectivity? (Sorry my knowledge of Lie algebra cohomology is very limited.)

Comment: 1. Unfortunately, the only explanation of why tensoring with $\mathbb{C}[t]$ does not change the homology of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ that I know is not very direct: namely, one can compute the homology of $\mathfrak{sl}_n\otimes\mathbb{C}[t]/(t^k)$ (this is not easy, but can be done, see the paper of Fishel, Grojnowski, and Teleman http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v168-n1-p05.pdf), and observe that all the cycles not coming from $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ live in degrees that are quite high (at least $k$), so as $k$ goes to infinity, none of them survive.

Comment: 2. As for using the adjoint action, this was a bit of a gut feeling about what to try - use it to decompose the standard complex, and see what happens. I do not have much time in the coming few days, but I will try to look at it a bit later. It would help if you give some ideas of what kinds of proofs and techniques in Lie algebra cohomology you are familiar with, and why, if your experience is so limited, you are interested in this particular question! :-)